# How to remove a button with its own onPressed function

Tags: flutter

Edit: Adding a 20 milliseconds delay after the line that sets the opacity to 0 worked.

I have a FAB that takes a screenshot. But I don't want it in the screenshot. Therefore it is the child of a visibility widget and the first thing it does to make itself invisible. However, the rest of the function doesn't run and gives the error:

> it's dangerous to look up a dead widget's ancestors

Opacity doesn't work because, I am guessing, even though it has 0 opacity it's still part of the widget tree and its included in the screenshot.

How can I keep the widget but make it invisible in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your container with a display condition

```dart
child: (showBtn ?
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(() => showBtn = false),
    )
  :
    Container()
  ),
```

Comment: Still dead parent error. Only thing that works is the delay after opacity set.

Comment: I guess someone more familiar with this would need the actual code to understand the issue. Another workaround could be to use my method above to remove size, padding, text background color etc from the button. Then, I would assume it is still active, you just can no longer see it

Comment: From the documentation: By default, the visible property controls whether the child is included in the subtree or not; when it is not visible, the replacement child (typically a zero-sized box) is included instead. So the widget isn't in the subtree and therefore is dead while invisible. Opacity on the other hand does what you suggested with the container.

Comment: but as you said, opacity doesn't work with the screen shot. With the method above applied as in my last comment, the size goes to zero and it also has no rendered content . So this should be invisible on the screenshot, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Visibility**

```
 bool visibility = true;

    Visibility(
            visible: visibility,
            child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
              setState(() => visibility = false);
    
              screenshotCapture().then((img) {
                setState(() => visibility = true);
              });
              
            }),
          ),
```

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
widgetVisible = true;
//Now somewhere where you add the button
widgetVisible?FlatButton(
   onPressed:(){
      setState((){
          widgetVisible=false;
       });
   }  
):Container()
```